# Convert dataframe column with values in the form of a list into a string in the same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is how the pandas dataframe looks like:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | ['Bb1'] | [54] | [84.0] |
| A2 | ['Bb2'] | [63] | [nan] |

Following is how the dataframe should be:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Bb1 | 54 | 84.0 |
| A2 | Bb2 | 63 | nan |

Answer (score 2):

As of pandas 1.3.0:

```
df.explode(['B', 'C', 'D'])
```

Or before:

```
df.set_index('A').apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
```

Comment: Before solution not working on pandas `1.2.4`

Comment: @MuhammadHassan On `1.1.3`, you probably need to run `eval` on the dataframe.

Comment: Yes got it, `eval` is what needs to be run before. Thanks